# sorting list of tuple based on engineering unit

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to sort list into following way.

```
data = [('18.3G', 'pgaur'), ('29.6G', 'adsoni'), ('5.51G', 'keyur'), ('10.8G', 'adityac')]

sorted(data, key= lambda x:x[0])
```

but it is not sorting data.

Comment: How do you want to sort the data? Is it by key or by value?

Comment: it is sorting the data but alphanumerically since they are strings and not numbers. Also you are not saving the resulting list anywhere.

Comment: `sorted(data, key= lambda x:x[1])` will sort the data by value in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2):

To sort numbers in the way that makes sense to humans, you have to make sure that they are presented as numbers and not as text:

- e.g., '5' is a string representing a number, not a number so
  `example_list = ['5', '10']` if sorted would yield `['10', '5']
  because what's compared is '5' against '1'; one character at a time.

To get the result you probably want, you have to do the following:

```
data = [('18.3G', 'pgaur'), ('29.6G', 'adsoni'), ('5.51G', 'keyur'), ('10.8G', 'adityac')]

sorted_list = sorted(data, key=lambda x: float(x[0][:-1]))
print(sorted_list)
# prints [('5.51G', 'keyur'), ('10.8G', 'adityac'), ('18.3G', 'pgaur'), ('29.6G', 'adsoni')]
```

Notice the slicing on the `x[0]`. It takes all characters in `x[0]` apart from the last one (`'G'`) since that would mess up the sorting of the number. Then the sliced `x[0]` is converted to float with `float()` and used for the sorting. Finally the results are saved in a new list.

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(data, key= lambda x:float(x[0][:][:-1]))
```

Will give you what you want.

This is sorting by the first element of the tuple x[0]
[:] copies the rest of the tuple, [:-1] up to the last digit (excludes G)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you need a key function that returns a numeric value. Let's suppose that you can use `k`, `m` and `g` as multipliers. This code does no error checking which is, as usual, left as an exercise for the reader.

```
def sortkey(pair):
    num = pair[0][:-1]
    mult = pair[0][-1].lower()
    num = float(num)
    mult = {'k': 1000, 'm': 1000000, 'g': 1000000000}[mult]
    return num*mult
```

Comment: I assumed that 'G' stands for gravity acceleration and not 'Giga' but interesting.

Comment: If it's constant then @ev.'s solution will probably be quicker